# How do I change the web adress of a list?

Tags: list, filter

I deleted a default list view and the web adress didn't change with that. So now it search for List/Old.View.aspx even though Old.View doesn't exist. This makes the site unavailable.

How do I point it to another list view? I've tried changing the default list view to another one but that didn't seem to solve it.

Comment: when you change the default list view, what problem are you facing?

Comment: When enter that specific list, it points you to a web adress with a list view that doesn't exist. I want it to point to a list view that exists, Allitems.aspx for example, so this site is available.

Comment: I deleted a default list view in SharePoint Designer. It seems like SharePoint doesn't collaborate with Designer on that part, since it still looks for a web adress with a deleted list view. I can manually change the web adress from Old.View.aspx to New.View.Aspx and enter the list... but I want this to work automatically like it did before.

Comment: So even when I change the default list view to something else, it still points you to that old view that I've deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new view and click the 'Make this the default view' checkbox.

This will be your default view from now on and obviously you can build it according to your requirements.

Comment: That did not sovle my problem. It still points me to the deleted list view and thus, making the site unavailable.